# Cannot obtain IE object in AutoIt script - _IESTATUS_NoMatch

Tags: internet-explorer, autoit, mcafee

I'm trying to automate GUI which utilizes an embedded IE instance (ClassnameNN: Internet Explorer_server1). But I cannot obtain/attach IE object, tried multiple ways and all of them return error `_IESTATUS_NoMatch`. To be more specific I'm automating McAfee antivirus:

```
AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)

$oie = _IEAttach("McAfee AntiVirus", "embedded")
$oie = _IEAttach("McAfee AntiVirus", "embedded", 1)
$oie = _IEAttach("[CLASS:Internet Explorer_Server; INSTANCE:1]", "embedded")
$oie = _IEAttach("[CLASS:Internet Explorer_Server; INSTANCE:1]", "text")
$oie = _IEAttach("", "instance", 1)
$oie = _IEAttach("")
$oie = _IEAttach("", "embedded")
$sText = _IEBodyReadText($oie)

$h_result = WinGetHandle("McAfee AntiVirus", "")
$o_result = __IEControlGetObjFromHWND($h_result)

; each _IEAttach() returns:
; --> IE.au3 T3.0-1 Warning from function _IEAttach, $_IESTATUS_NoMatch
```

I tried this with IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11 - the same result every time.

All I need is to read text from McAfee scan results. Any other workaround to this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason you use the same variable for 7 _IEAttach() calls?

Comment: @Mr. Hargrove Cause he is just testing if any of the tries is a success.

Comment: thanks for the clarity Milos.

Answer (score 1):

Does this works for you?

```
#RequireAdmin
Opt("WinSearchChildren", 1) ;0=no, 1=search children also
#include <IE.au3> 

AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode", 2)
$HWND = WinGetHandle("McAfee AntiVirus", "")
$oie = _IEAttach($HWND, "embedded")

ConsoleWrite(_IEDocReadHTML($oIE) & @CRLF)
```

Comment: its the same - _IEAttach() returns _IESTATUS_NoMatch

Comment: If that window visible? Is the title correct?
How did you got the title text?

Comment: Thanks for trying, but still the same NoMatch.
Here is a screenshot of the window I'm trying to capture https://db.tt/yCpjVzro  + a summary from AU3 Info tool https://db.tt/6Ye6afU0
I can also record a screencast, if that helps. I just cannot figure out if its McAfee odd GUI design, or its me using AutoIt improperly